# Weird bugs with flying table texts when printing in Chrome and using the 'page-break-inside' css

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing

It appears a **duplicated white text** in the **middle of the table** only when print:

[image]

I checked and this duplicated cell text only uses **simple css styles**.
(nothing like 'position' or 'display' css)

Any clue?

Comment: Is this the output of a system you made? If so, please show us the css and html. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi Acrux, yes the html is mine and works well in web so is only a print issue :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is some **bugs** in chrome around table **thead**'s and **page-break-inside** css style.
(there is a lot of different bug reports about this).

I finally solved this, removing `<thead>` tags and work only with common rows `<tr>`.